# Highcharts loaded via ajax, issue to dynamically create yAxis

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, highcharts, yaxis

I have a page that dynamically updates a HighCharts graph from a multiselect dropdown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- FIELDS -->
    <div id="fields">
        <form method="post" action="">
            <select id="f" name="f[]" multiple>
                <option value="rss1" select>1RSS(dB)</option>
                <option value="rss2">2RSS(dB)</option>
                <option value="rqly">RQly(%)</option>
                <option value="rsnr">RSNR(dB)</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- GRAPH -->
    <div id="graph">No selection</div>

    <script>    
        var updateChart = function(json) {
            // console.log(json)
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'graph',
                    type: 'line',
                    zoomType: 'x'
                },
                title: { text: null },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        label: {
                            connectorAllowed: false
                        },
                        pointStart: 0
                    }
                },
                series: []
            }

            options.series = json;
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

            // update yaxis
            for (i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
                if(i==0) {
                    // it seems that a yAxis already exist when graph is initialized. Did not find a smarter way to destroy it...
                    chart.yAxis[0].update({ title: { text: json[i].name }});
                } else {
                    chart.addAxis({ title: { text: json[i].name } });
                }
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#f').change(function() {
                var requestParams = { f: $('#f').val() };
                $.post('analysisajax.php', requestParams, updateChart);             
            });
        });    

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Now, my `analysisajax.php` file looks like this:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/json");
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

$jsonObject = array();
$yaxis = 0;

foreach($_POST["f"] as $v) {

    $data = array();
    $sql = "SELECT $v FROM log WHERE id_user = " . $_SESSION["id_user"];
    $result = $link->query($sql);

    while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        $data[] = $row[0];
    }

    $jsonObject[] = array(
            "name" => $v,
            "data" => $data,
            "yAxis"=>$yaxis
        );
    $yaxis++;
}

$myJSON = json_encode($jsonObject, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
echo $myJSON;

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

When I'm selecting 1 value from the form, the graph loads without problem, but as soon as more than 1 value is selected from the dropdown, the graph fails with the following trace:

```
highcharts.src.js:498 Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #18: www.highcharts.com/errors/18
    at Object.a.error (highcharts.src.js:498)
    at highcharts.src.js:32669
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at r.<anonymous> (highcharts.src.js:32621)
    at a.fireEvent (highcharts.src.js:2635)
    at r.bindAxes (highcharts.src.js:32618)
    at r.init (highcharts.src.js:32482)
    at a.Chart.initSeries (highcharts.src.js:26913)
    at highcharts.src.js:28765
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

I feel that the issue is coming from my dynamic construction of `yAxis` but can't find a way to make it work. Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I noticed that removing the `yAxis` key from the `$jsonObject` in the `analysisajax.php` script results in no error. Yaxis are added without error on the graph, dynamically, but without scale.

Comment: The issue seems to come from the fact that axis should be created prior to the series. In my case, I'm creating series, and then updating "live" the axis.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually made it work with the following solution:

In the `analysisajax.php` script, I no longer generate the `yaxis`. I only send `name` and `data`.

The code to generate the graph now looks like this:

```
    var updateChart = function(json) {
        //console.log(json)
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'graph',
                type: 'line',
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            title: { text: null },
            yAxis:[],
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    label: {
                        connectorAllowed: false
                    },
                    pointStart: 0
                }
            },
            series: [],
            tooltip: { shared: true }
        }

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

        // update axis and series
        for (i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
            // add axis
            chart.addAxis({ title: { text: json[i].name } });

            // add serie
            var a = chart.series.length;
            var seriesOptions = {
                name: json[i].name,
                data: json[i].data,
                yAxis: a
            }
            chart.addSeries(seriesOptions,true);
            chart.options.series.push(seriesOptions);       
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#f').change(function() {
            var requestParams = { f: $('#f').val() };
            $.post('analysisajax.php', requestParams, updateChart);             
            //return false;
        });
    });
```